# Download a "huge" Facebook conversation, in full HTML, with emoticons and attachments

Tags: facebook, download

I *need* to save a "huge" Facebook conversation, in HTML form, with emoticons, photos, and attachments as I see on the browser.

There is *no* solution at this time.

1. With the Facebook option that lets you download an entire conversation, we can *only* get the text, with *no* emoticons, *no* photos or any other attachments.
2. I *cannot* "scroll" then copy & paste a *huge* conversation. We are talking about 200,000 messages. Every browser would explode on a 64 bit system also with an insane amount of RAM or swap. There is no way.
3. I've tried to "automate" the manual scroll by writing an application that interacts with the browser, putting the link of the begin of conversation on the mobile version (m.facebook.com) and finding the "next" link, virtually clicking them, and making a loop until finding the "next day", then saving the HTML of a conversation of this day and looping again to the next day. *But*... it's not working. First, Facebook detects that the browsing is "strange", and it uses a "strange" version of its style. I've tried to force every possible browser's "user agent", but it doesn't work. Second, with an OLE object instance of the browser (IE or Chrome), I can't use the "Save as.." method.

So, I've tried but haven't found any solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I download all messages from Facebook?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27640/how-can-i-download-all-messages-from-facebook)

Answer (score 2):

Have you also tried some generic web crawlers/downloaders like HTTrack or Teleporter Pro?

Also there are some dedicated 'Facebook downloaders', mostly commercially, but you may want to have a googlook.

Also, see the solutions at [How can I download all messages from Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27640/how-can-i-download-all-messages-from-facebook) .

Comment: Thanks for reply.
No, I can't use a simple "downloader", because the problem is that is "impossible" to manually scroll the entire "huge" conversation without the "explosion" of any browser; if it were possible, I could simply use the "Save as" feature of the browser.

Comment: @CorradoCasoni I see. Yesterday I was somewhat playing with the `@start=` parameter of the mobile URL as mentioned in one of the answers linked and it seams you can easily download the whole conversation one chunk at time, with some very basic iterated script.

Comment: The &start= parameter is working (so I can reach the top of the "huge" conversation trying approximative numbers) but then @page_size parameter mentioned in the solution that you have reported, is no longer working. Even if he was working, I could never use a &PAGE_SIZE = [huge number] because any browser will explode with 200,000 posts .
I tried SocialSafe, but does not save messages with emoticons and attachments. "They're working on a solution ," they say :/

Comment: Yes I have also experienced &page_size working no more. Anyway, as I say you can/should donwload your whole conversation one piece a time, iterating the `&start` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have the solution for you. But it might be 2 years late anyways, if you are still looking for a way to download your Facebook messages, here is the solution. There is a chrome extension called [Message/Chat Downloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/messagechat-downloader/nkinapjekllgfipphkgpmombekfclghe). It is fast and does the job very well. Good Luck and let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Please disclose if you are affiliated with the product in any way. Thanks!

Comment: @jonsca ya I created the chrome extension

Answer (score 0):

There's an extension for Chrome that can do such a job, it can save a Facebook chat with all the emoticons, pictures, videos and other files present in the chat.

Here's the link to the website where you can download it: [Messages Saver for Facebook](https://chatsaver.org).